# Log telnet/ssh command but bypass password field c/c++ socket programing

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm trying to write a telnet/ssh like application in C/C++. The application works like below:

1. User run this app, connect to remote device
2. The remote device MAY or may NOT ask for password
3. user type command to control the remote device or password to authenticate.
4. The application log all commands user entered but do not log password.

If user entered a command, the remote side will echo the user input back to user. plus it will return command result. 
If user entered password, remote side won't echo back.

So I thought it can be easily done by saving the user input command to string A and the remote echo back to another string B. If string B contains string A, then, it is a command. If string B doesn't contain string A. then it is password.

The logic sound simple, but when it comes to implementation, I found it is hard than i expected. It is because it is not easy to save the "full command" to string A and echo back to string B due to the nature of socket --- e.g. a packet might have sent/revived but might sit in the buffer... As a result, string A and B sometimes contains only part of the command, sometimes A contains some of last command and some of next command...

Is there a decent solution for this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

George

Comment: This is interesting what you are planning to do. Can you share what you have done till now, it seems more of a requirement.

Comment: So why not log just whatever the remote site prints?

Comment: Because the remote side print the command plus command result. The command result can be fairly large...

Comment: There is no reliable way to differentiate regular input or password prompt. Prompt for sudo may exhibit some patterns, but to some extend you never know what is potentially sensitive information. How about manage it in higher level, like provide a mechanism (or button) to "type password/sensitive information" which the app do not log?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i completely understand your problem.

*Based on what i understood*

If you are sending the command in string A, you can handle the password request and not store the password in A or do any action based on the event request for passowrd.

pseudocode:
`while(read_from_socket(buff_B)){
  if(buff_B=="Password:"){send_to_socket(buff_A);/*Which contains password*/}
  else {log(buff_A);send_to_socket(buff_A);}
}`

I suggest you look at some open src authentication programs.

Comment: I want to log all command user typed in for auditing purpose. But I don't want to log password to the log for obvious reason. This is where the difficulty comes in--- There is no easy way for this application to tell whether user typed in a command or typed in a password. For the authentication part, it works e.g. If remote side ask for password, it sends me "Password:" prompt . I'm able to type in password and get authenticated (and password is not displayed on the screen).

Comment: @FlatWorld Each time your read from the prompt check if it's "Password" if it is then  don't log else log it. i'll edit my answer

Answer (score -1):

There is no reliable way to do this. The closest aproximation I can think of is logging the echo that the telnet server sends you. That has its own problems, of course - how do you decide what's echo and what's output? Mathing to input may help, but still - it's a tough problem.